# Jquery Find Selected Element via Selector vs Method

Tags: jquery

I've a little confusion here, which is better to choose either directly used the selector or method in jquery

For example :

```
$("div p:first") with $("div p").first() -> it's same right
```

Are there any condition that we choose selector rather than method? 
For example because selector run faster? (example only not the truth)

Comment: You can benchmark them to see which is faster

Comment: `.first()` is better against `:first` pseudo-selector.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you though? Browsers aren't that stupid anymore, those repetitive tests are trivial to optimize away.

Comment: Speed of selector lookup is irrelevant. Pay attention to how you append elements and how often you modify visible elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're actually almost the same

1. `$('div p:first')` will return you the element once the first element of `p` in a `div` is found.
2. `$('div p').first()` will iterate all `p` elements in `div`, then return the first one.

If you check from console, they have different `prevObject` property.

jQuery uses this object as a stack of the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state. As they need this for their [end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/) function.

*Taken from jQuery*

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    ...
    end: function() {
        return this.prevObject || this.constructor();
    }
};
```

If you want to talk about speed comparison, I'd suggest to go with the first one. Since you would not need to traverse to all `p` in a `div`